# Using fopen with a file behind HTTP authentication

Tags: php, fopen

I'm trying to tidy up my error logs. When I use fopen to retrieve a file behind HTTP auth and it fails, I get the error message:

```
fopen: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Is there a check I can do before using fopen to see if this would fail?

Here's an example URL: http://12345:12345@datatransfer.cj.com/datatransfer/files/products.zip

Answer (score 0):

I did this by checking the file headers for authentication:

```
$file_headers = get_headers($url);
if (!$file_headers) return "No headers found";
else if (strpos($file_headers[0], '401 Unauthorized') > -1) return "Authorization required";        
else if (strpos($file_headers[0], '404 Not Found') > -1) return "404 Not Found";
else {
    // now safe to use fopen...
}
```